# Toastr Alert Asp.Net Vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, toastr

Im trying to do some alert messages on a web form in visual studio vb, but it keeps giving me this error when i try and code it dynamically in the action method
"**only content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains content controls**"

i have left the old code in where it just produces a label error message into the HTML

getting a blue wave line underneath this line

```
popupScript = "<script language='javascript'>" + "showErrorToast();" + "</script>"
```

jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showErrorToastr() {
    toastr.warning('Please enter at least 3 characters of the organisation name')
}
```

Vb Action method when cancel button its clicked

```
 Protected Sub btnSelect0_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim popupScript As String = ""
    If txtorgname.Text = "" Then
        lblerror.Text = "Please enter at least 3 characters of the organisation name"
        txtorgname.Focus()
        popupScript = "<script language='javascript'>" + "showErrorToast();" + "</script>"
    ElseIf Len(txtorgname.Text) < 3 Then
        lblerror.Text = "Please enter at least 3 characters of the organisation name"
        txtorgname.Focus()
    ElseIf Len(txtorgname.Text) > 50 Then
        lblerror.Text = "Organisation name too long. Max 50"
        txtorgname.Focus()
    Else
        BindData()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`showErrorToast` does not exist in your example, but `showErrorToastr` does.

Try that change. If it doesn't work, please comment.